# C# access configuration settings during ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, appsettings

Is there a working method accessing configuration values during `ConfigureServices()` in C# netCore? I have a dapr settings added as 'options pattern', but need the values in the same section immediately.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
{
    services.ConfigureOptions<DaprConfigConfigBinder>();
    var daprSettings = ctx.Configuration.Get<DaprConfig>(); // ????
    var daprClient = new DaprClientBuilder().UseGrpcEndpoint(daprSettings.gcprEndpoint).Build();
}
```

where

```
public class DaprConfig
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("stateStoreName")]
    public string stateStoreName { get; set; } = null!;

    [ConfigurationKeyName("gcprEndpoint")]
    public string gcprEndpoint { get; set; } = null!;
}

internal class DaprConfigConfigBinder : IConfigureOptions<DaprConfig>
{
    private const string SECTION_NAME = "Dapr";
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public DaprConfigConfigBinder(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void Configure(DaprConfig options)
    {
        this.config.GetSection(SECTION_NAME).Bind(options);
    }
}
```

and `appsettings.json` important part is:

```
{
    "Dapr": {
        "stateStoreName": "statestore",
        "gcprEndpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:13109"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
var config= new DaprConfig();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("Dapr").Bind(config);
```

Comment: Thx! Is there any chance to get the values using the `DaprConfigConfigBinder`?

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak maybe this might help https://andrewlock.net/access-services-inside-options-and-startup-using-configureoptions/#under-the-hood